# The composition $\pi_{\#}\tau$ of the induced map of singular chain complex and the transfer map is a multiplication by $n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading about Transfer homomorphisms from Hatcher and there he has said that the composition $\pi_{\#}\tau$ is a multiplication by $n$.
Why is this true?

Here $\pi_{\#}:C_k(\widetilde X)\to C_k(X)$ is the induced map of singular chain complex in correspondence to the $n$-sheeted covering space $\pi:\widetilde X\to X$ and $\tau: C_k(X)\to C_k(\widetilde X)$ is the transfer map (the homomorphism in the opposite direction) which assigns to a singular simplex $\sigma:\triangle^k\to X$ the sum of the n distinct lifts $\widetilde\sigma:\triangle^k\to\widetilde X$.

P.S. Please elaborate your statements and use proper mathematical statements.

Comment: Isn't this very clear? When you apply $\pi_#$ it sends each of the $n$ lifts in your sum back to the original simplex, so is the same as multiplication by $n$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip yes intuitively clear but OP asks about technical help.

Comment: @Jale'dejaled that is the technical definition!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma$ be a $k$ simplex in the base. Then $$\tau(\sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^n \widetilde{\sigma}_i$$ where the sum is over the $n$ lifts of $\sigma$. Hence
$$\pi_\sharp\tau(\sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^n\pi_\sharp \widetilde{\sigma}_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma = n\cdot\sigma.$$